# Meu arquivo CSS é muito grande e fica difícil manter a legibilidade

Tags: css, css3, desempenho, sharepoint

O meu Arquivo CSS está perto de 10 mil linhas.
Está ficando muito complicado dar manutenção nesse arquivo.
em sua versão de Desenvolvimento o arquivo "pesa" 170kb e em sua versão minificada, "apenas" 128kb

Alguns pontos a serem considerados:

- Evitar o trafego de rede desnecessário
- Evitar import

existe alguma técnica ou ferramenta que facilite a manutenção desse tipo de arquivo e mais importante, nessa escala?

Comment: Separar seu CSS em vários arquivos, agrupando por regras similares (*menu.css*, *rodape.css*) e usar um automatizador de tarefas como o Gruntjs para gerar um único arquivo CSS.

Comment: Veja esses links:
http://tableless.com.br/sass-um-outro-metodo-de-escrever-css/
http://blog.caelum.com.br/css-menos-sofrido-com-sass/ Existem outros pré-processadores como stylus e less que são muito bons tbm.
Abs

Comment: fiquei curioso em saber como conseguiu fazer um css chegar a 10 mil linhas.. rsrs

Comment: @DanielOmine em um app online que fiz recentemente pra um escritório (pequeno) o css possuia 7mil linhas, com sass consegui reduzir para 3-4mil

Comment: @DanielOmine se trata de um portal para uma instituição governamental.  é importante que isso não afete desempenho... e lembre-se nem sempre um código grande é um código ruim.

Comment: Carregue somente os estilos que aquela página específica precisa usar. Só isso seria suficiente.

Comment: Entendi o ponto @DanielOmine. Mas esse arquivo ficaria na master page,  é uma abordagem diferente do tradicional ASP.Net. Essa Solução seria o melhor caminho caso eu tivesse controle sobre aquele "headPlaceHolder" O uso de Sandbox solution no sharepoint me permite apenas trabalhar com Javascript e o css fica retido nesse arquivo. O nosso colega CelsomTrindade Deixou uma resposta interessante que estou explorando agora. Logo mais contarei os detalhes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Uma alternativa, que é a que eu utilizo, seria utilização de [SASS](http://sass-lang.com/).

Apesar de ter algumas características diferentes de `css`, a lógica é a mesma, você apenas vem a ganhar com a utilização do `SASS` (pelo menos essa é minha opinião).

> Está ficando muito complicado dar manutenção

O `SASS` vai ser uma ótima ferramenta para melhorar a manutenção de arquivos. Um dos maiores ganhos é o reaproveitamento de código.

O que mais me chamou atenção foi a possibilidade de estruturar o `css` em cascata de modo mais.. organizado e intuitivo. Supondo que você tenha este código:

```
.navbar ul {
    margin:0;
}
.navbar ul li {
    padding:0 8px;
}
```

Você pode simplificar e escrever assim:

```
.navbar {
    ul {
        margin:0;
        li {
            padding:0 8px;
        }
    }
}
```

Mais exemplos, digamos que você tenha este código `css`:

```
.classe {
    background: red;
    width: 180px;
}
```

E depois você deseja utilizar este mesmo pedaço de código em outra classe. Ao invés de reescrever, você pode incluir, com um `@include`, usando um `@mixin` ou `@extend` (lendo mais sobre o `sass` você vai ver as propriedades mais a fundo), ficando assim:

```
@mixin meuEstilo {
    background: red;
    width: 180px;
}

.classe {
    @include meuEstilo
}
.outra-classe {
    @include meuEstilo
}
```

Ambos serão compilados para `css` assim:

```
.classe {
    background: red;
    width: 180px;
}
.outra-classe {
    background: red;
    width: 180px;
}
```

Além disso, você também pode trabalhar com variáveis, por exemplo:

```
@mixin animacao($valor) {
    transform: translateY($valor);
}

.classe {
    @include animacao(50%);
}
.outra-classe {
    @include animacao(80px);
}

//Compilado para
.classe {
    transform: translateY(50%);
}
.outra-classe {
    transform: translateY(80px);
}
```

Obs.: Eventualmente você verá a extensão `.scss` ela segue a mesma lógica do `.sass` mudando apenas a *syntax*. É mais uma questão de preferência do que de ganho/perda em utilizar um ou outro.

Com `SASS` você consegue um reaproveitamento de código muito melhor e também consegue estrutura melhor os seus arquivos. Eu, por exemplo, utilizo uma estrutura semelhante a essa:

```
-sass
    /base //arquivos base, como reset, normalize, etc.
        -reset.scss
        -normalize.scss
    /variables //arquivo de variaveis, como tempo de animação, cor principal, etc.
        -cores.scss
        -tempo.scss
        -font.scss
    /ui //elementos comuns, como forms, buttons, etc..
        -forms.scss
        -buttons.scss
        -footer.scss
        -navbar.scss
    /pages //páginas individuais, como noticias, contato, produto
        -noticia.scss
        -servico.scss
        -contato.scss
```

Deste modo, cada arquivo `.scss` que possuo tem +- 100 linhas e o arquivo compilado geral, normalmente fica em torno de 20-30kb para um projeto que antes possuia 4-5 mil linhas de `css` bruto.

---

Para compilar o seu `SASS` para `CSS`, você vai precisar de algum compilador, seja ele um software ou, os mais comuns usados, `gulp` ou `grunt`.

Essa parte eu deixo a seu critério, pois é muito preferência qual deles usar. Eu particularmente uso `grunt`, pois já utilizava em outras áreas dos meus projetos. Mas tenha em mente que você vai precisar usar um processador para compilar o seu sass em `css`.

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Celsom estou explorando o Sass neste momento, esse css (ou scss) será de uma solução sharepoint, isso significa que eu precisaria antes de subir para o servidor, eu teria que compila-los. A pergunta é, é obrigatório o uso de compiladores para o Sass?

Comment: @okevinlira sim, precisaria. O browser não consegue ler nem processar um (ou diversos) arquivos sass, scss ou less, por exemplo. Por isso precisamos de uma processador.

Comment: Adorei o Sass e estou utilizando fortemente. adotei também o compass de fato facilitou muito.

Comment: @okevinlira imagino que tenha sido um caminho sem voltas! hahaha Uma vez com Sass.. Nunca mais sem Sass